# Can I use ajax in gjs or any alternatives method?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

[gnome-sehll-extension]

I need read other web pages and parse the obtained JSON files.

The office example is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.xxx/yyyy',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        q: query,
        appid: appid,
        salt: salt,
        from: from,
        to: to,
        sign: sign
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I have get the result data use `POST` manaully.

now how can I use ajax mothed? or use some library to do it? or call `curl` command to get the result?

Comment: I searched for a long time and found that GJS may have more restrictions. For example, the local files in the directory cannot be listed, and the network cannot be accessed directly. So I did this with the external command curl.

Comment: `gi.Soup` can use `get` to access the network. But I haven't studied whether `post` can do it. thank JustPerfection.